# How to write nested single query in Laravel Eloquent

Tags: laravel, eloquent

These are the two queries I am firing. I want to make it simpler and faster. how should I do it?

```
$parentList = Category::select('parent_id')->groupBy('parent_id')->get()->toArray();

$categories = Category::whereNotIn('categories.id', $parentList)->get();
```

Table categories have following columns(
id,
parent_id,
name)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Make this relation in your Category Model as :-

```
public function parents()
{
    return $this->hasOne('App\Category', 'parent_id', 'id');
}
```

Then simply use this relation as :-

```
$categories = Category::whereDoesntHave('parents')->get();
```

Comment: Thank You. This works really well. Just one change in relationship of parents hasOne.